# Excel storing numbers incorrectly

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

If I type a value into a cell it stores it as expected, but if I set the value through VBA code, it stores it incorrectly.  To be more specific, I calculated the height of something and the resulting value is 1.15. The number displays correctly, but when I click on the cell, the number actually being stored is 1.14999997615814.  There is another cell that uses this number or another number based on a condition. That cell always displays the actual stored number (1.14999997615814) which is incorrect.  This is for a technical document being reviewed by government engineers so even a small deviation will cause the document to be rejected.  I've tried storing the number as text (no difference), rounding it before storing (no difference), calculating it as single or double precision before storing, again with no difference in what Excel does.  This doesn't happen with all values but when the calculated result was 1.15 it exhibits this behavior.  The only thing that causes the number to be stored correctly is to manually type it in and that defeats the whole purpose of having the value calculated.  Anyone have any insight into what is happening and how I can force, coerce, or bribe Excel into behaving properly?

TIA.

Comment: May be you have never noticed the possible function `ROUND(,,,)` used in VBA code,,, otherwise this never happens. Please [Edit] post as share the VBA code with us.

Comment: It's called **15 significant digit floating-point arithmetic**. The answer may actually be *1.14999997615814* or floating point maths 'corrected' *1.5* to *1.14999997615814*. What was the actual original calculation?

Comment: See [Floating-point arithmetic may give inaccurate results in Excel](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/78113/floating-point-arithmetic-may-give-inaccurate-results-in-excel) for an explanation of what is going on.  And post the code you are using for help with how to handle this.

Comment: Yes, please share the code that caused you a problem. I get 1.15 in a cell with this code, `ActiveCell.Value = Round(1 + 0.14999997615814, 2)`.

Comment: The code is exactly what you would think...I am doing the math and assigning it to the cell with the code "Range("L24").value=nResult".  The actual value I am storing is 1.15...not the oddball number I'm getting (0.25+0.0747+0.5006+0.0747+0.25=1.15)  And yes, it LOOKS right when you see the value in the cell, but when you try to use the value it is 1.49999...  All of the answers I am getting make sense if I only care about the display value (I'm not...I'm using that value in other calculations) or if I were rounding numbers during my calculations but I'm not.  I found a solution though...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still don't know what actually caused the issue.  I won't bore you with the code used to achieve the result - in summary it is just locating the numbers to add and adding them.  The values are (0.0747*2)+(0.25*2)+.05006 which equals 1.15.  The only fix that worked was to assign the results to the cell as text and then convert to a number like this:

```
    ws.Range("L24").Value = "'" & JobSettings.BrgHeight
    ws.Range("L24").Select
    Selection.NumberFormat = "General"
```